# Generic Parameter 'T' Could not be Inferred: Array Parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a generic function that accepts records conforming to `Protocol Printable`.

```
class Printer
{
   func printRecords<T: Record where T: Printable>(records: [T], completion: ((e: NSError?) -> Void)? )
   {
       // do print stuff here
       var data = NSMutableData()
       for r in records
       {
          data.appendData(r.printableData)
       }

       let error = self.printData(data)
       completion?(e: error)
   }
}
```

Here is the `Record` and `Printable` declaration and implementation:

```
protocol Printable
{
   var printableData: NSData { get }
}

public class Record: NSManagedObject
{
   // property declaration here  
}

public class Person: Record
{
   // property declaration here  
}

public class Address: Record
{
   // property declaration here  
}

// implement Printabl
extension Address: Printable
{
   var printData: NSData 
   { 
     // format print data here...
     .
     .
     .

     return data 
   }
}
```

But when I call the method like this:

```
// was initially inserted into coredata via
// NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Address", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Address
let address: Address = ...

// This line: Generic Parameter 'T' Could not be Inferred
printer.printRecords([address], completion: { (e: NSError?) in
   // handle print completion here
})
```

I got error:

> Generic Parameter 'T' Could not be Inferred

Comment: Where does `record` come from? Btw, you don't need `where T: Printable` clause as `Record` already implements that protocol.

Comment: Okay will update the question.

Comment: @ozgur, just updated the code.

Comment: What's the possible cause why I'm getting such error?

Comment: It is so weird. Looks like Swift is unable to infer the type of `[address]` unless you assign it to a variable. Calling it like `printer.printRecords([address] as [Address], ...` will work but I don't know why it couldn't infer that in the first place.

Comment: Maybe `[ ]` does not tell the compiler what's really inside. So there is a need to explicitly tell that it's an array of Address as `[Address]( )`. Well anyway, maybe swift wants us to be clear as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it tells. You can test it by: `let array = [address]` and check the type of `array`. Probably compiler thinks the array's type is either `[Address]` or `[Record]` but since not all record types are printable, it complaint. But i am not sure.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. Declaring a `let addresses = [address];` and using that makes the problem go way, though the code is functionally the same.